# vim: gq ignores open quotes when wrapping text

Tags: python, vim

Suppose I have a list of strings in a file (a Python script, for example) like this:

```
my_list_of_numbers = ["one two",
    "three four",
    "five six",
    "seven eight",
    "nine ten",
    "eleven twelve"]
```

If I make a visual selection of this text, I can use `gq` to wrap the text to get:

```
my_list_of_numbers = ["one two", "three four", "five six", "seven eight", "nine
    ten", "eleven twelve"]
```

However, the element `"nine ten"` is now split in half over two lines.

How do I wrap the text while avoiding entering a newline character inside an open quote? My desired result would look like this:

```
my_list_of_numbers = ["one two", "three four", "five six", "seven eight",
    "nine ten", "eleven twelve"]
```

Comment: Vim can't do it; you'd have to give it code to do so. `:help fp` (external formatter) and `:help fex` (vimscript formatter) for more details.

Comment: It seem that use `gq` won't have the indent in your example, right? By the way, if you want to get your desired result, put the cursor in first line, try`4JjJ`

Comment: @lord63.j Thanks for your contribution. `gq` will indent if you set `:filetype plugin on`, `:filetype indent on` and `:set ft=python`. `4JjJ` certainly does the job but it would require me to work out in my head how many lines would bring the line up to 80 characters.

Comment: This question belongs on vi.stackexchange.

Comment: but i think, it is possible to get the output in one line (with out line break). is it enough?

Comment: @SamjithDasan Yes it is. `6J`, for example will put them all on one line. But I would want it to adhere to an character limit.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't think that there is a reserved command to do this, but we can do it by 
make it to one line and then by regex, break it to your desired wish.

```
%s/\(.\{-}".\{-}".\{-}".\{-}".\{-}".\{-}".\{-}\)"/\1\r"/gec
```

just map the whole thing into a key. so as to make you easy.

Comment: Thanks for the effort but unfortunately this doesn't do exactly what I want. If the text within quotes is short, I would want more "words" on each line, and if they are longer I would want less - whereas this just puts three on each line.

Comment: @Zam -- I think you might have meant something more like `:s/\(\s*\)\(.\{-}".\{-}".\{-}".\{-}".\{-}".\{-}".\{-}\)\s*\ze"/\2\r/g` (0 indent) or `:s/^\(\s*\)\(.\{-}".\{-}".\{-}".\{-}".\{-}".\{-}".\{-}\)\s*\ze"/&\r\1/g` (keeps indent, but has to be run once per new line).  Your answer misplaced the quotation marks after the second line.

Answer (score 0):

Please save this script to a file and load in your vim.

```
vnoremap a d:call Replace(@")<CR>


function! Replace(arg1, ...)
            let Var = Myfun(a:arg1)
                call append(line('.') - 1,   [Var])
                silent! %s/@@newline@@/ /g
                silent! %s/@!@/\r/g
endfunc                                                                    

function! Myfun(s)
            let Var = a:s
                let Var = substitute(Var, '\n', '@@newline@@', 'g')
                let Var = substitute(Var, '\s\s*', ' ', 'g')
                let Varlength = strlen(substitute(Var, '\(.\{-}\".\{-}\"\,.\{-}\".\{-}\"\,.\{-}\".\{-}\"\,\)', '\1', 'g'))
                if Varlength < 120
                let Var = substitute(Var, '\(.\{-}\".\{-}\"\,.\{-}\".\{-}\"\,.\{-}\".\{-}\"\,\)', '\1@!@', 'g')
                else
                let Var = substitute(Var, '\(.\{-}\".\{-}\"\,.\{-}\".\{-}\"\,\)', '\1@!@', 'g')
                endif 
            return Var
endfunc
```

block the text and hit key "a"